# smooth scroll instead of redirect

Tags: javascript

so I have the following script / function that redirects the page to the top, or the "home page" if I could say so, in case of no activity for a certain time.

my issue is, I want it to smoothly scroll up to the top instead of just redirecting there, any suggestions ? ? ?

my code >>

```
<script>
    (function() {
    
        

        const idleDurationSecs = 60;    // X number of seconds
        const redirectUrl = '#top';  // Redirect idle users to this URL
        let idleTimeout; // variable to hold the timeout, do not modify
    
        const resetIdleTimeout = function() {

            
            // Clears the existing timeout
            if(idleTimeout) clearTimeout(idleTimeout);
    
            // Set a new idle timeout to load the redirectUrl after idleDurationSecs
            idleTimeout = setTimeout(() => location.href = redirectUrl, idleDurationSecs * 1000);
            
            
        };
    
        // Init on page load
        resetIdleTimeout();
    
        // Reset the idle timeout on any of the events listed below
        ['click', 'touchstart', 'mousemove'].forEach(evt => 
            document.addEventListener(evt, resetIdleTimeout, false)
        );
    
    })();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intention is not to change page, but actually scroll to the top then use the `scrollTo` method of `window`, as can be seen in this demo below:

```js
function scrollDemo() {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>long page</div>
<div>long page</div>
<div>long page</div>
<div>long page</div>
<div>long page</div>
<div>long page</div>
<div>long page</div>
<div>long page</div>
<div>long page</div>
<a href="#" onclick="scrollDemo(); return false;">To The Top</a>
```

As per the documentation for [`window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo):

> `Window.scrollTo()` scrolls to a particular set of coordinates in the document

In the case of your timeout method, instead of setting `location.href`, use `window.scrollTo()` instead:

```
idleTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        behavior: "smooth"
    });
}, idleDurationSecs * 1000);
```

Comment: THANKS!! that was pretty helpful and quick. it worked

Answer (score 1):

Clear timeout whenever you call `resetIdleTimeout`.

**Example below:**

```js
(function () {
  const idleDurationSecs = 5; // X number of seconds

  let idleTimeout;

  function resetIdleTimeout() {
    clearTimeout(idleTimeout);
    idleTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      window.scroll({
      top: 0, 
      left: 0, 
      behavior: 'smooth' 
    });
    }, idleDurationSecs * 1000);
  }

  // Reset the idle timeout on any of the events listed below
  ["click", "touchstart", "mousemove"].forEach(evt =>
    document.addEventListener(evt, resetIdleTimeout, false)
  );
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>line x</div>
      <div>End</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `scroll-behavior: smooth;` to the body css. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior

Comment: @naveen, Thanks for your reminder. I add ```window.scroll({
      top: 0, 
      left: 0, 
      behavior: 'smooth' 
    });``` instead.